# longest path no longer than average degree of vertices

Tags: graph-theory

I'm currently working on the following graph theory problem:

> For each integer $k \geq 1$, find a connected, non-complete graph G containing no $P_{2k+2}$ with $\bar{d} (G) \geq 2k-0.0001$.

In my notation $P_{2k+2}$ means path of edge length $2k+1$ and $\bar{d} (G)$ means average degree of vertices of $G$.

What I tried so far: for $k=1$ I drew a star. then the center vertex has degree $n$, the outer $n$ vertices each have degree $1$. This gives us an average degree of $\frac{2n}{n-1}$. For $n=20,000$ this term is bigger than the $2-0.0001$ from the question. Now for $k=2$ I'm stuck. Essentially I started viewing my star from above as a tree, where my center vertex is the root. Now I can make my tree higher, but only one higher, since the longest path goes from a leaf via the root to another leaf. But in all the variations of my tree I never found the one that worked to give me an average degree of almost $4(=2k)$, but maybe I simply haven't found the right one yet.

I would love to an idea of what that graph looks like, either just for $k=2$ or for all $k$. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Trees are never going to have average degree more than $2$. There is a generalization of the star that works, but it's not going to be a tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone in the future stumbling across this question:

The solution is bipartite graphs! You have $k$ vertices in one part and $n$ in the other. Then you connect each vertex with every vertex in the opposite set. That means the longest possible path is $P_{2k+1}$ (edge length $2k$). The average degree is $\frac{2kn}{n+k}$ which goes to $2k$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Edit: There was another comment, where we discussed how to arrive at that solution, sadly the author deleted that comment.

Comment: (+1) Wonderful solution to this great question.