# Lower Bound on Length of Longest Path in a Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph on $n$ vertices having $e$ edges. I can show that there is a path in $G$ of length at least $\lfloor e/n\rfloor$.

> **Question.** I am looking for better bounds.

Here is the argument for the $\lfloor e/n\rfloor$ bound.

Assume inductively that the claimed bound holds for all graphs having fewer than $n$ vertices.
Assume by way of contradiction that there is a graph $G = (V, E)$ $n$ vertices for which the claimed bound does not hold. By computation we thus have $n\geq 3$. We may further assume that $|E|$ is the smallest possible. Say $e = |E|$. Thus there must be a path of length at least $\lfloor (e-1)/n\rfloor$ in $G$ (since we can delete one edge and the resulting graph has fewer edges). Let $v_0, v_1, \ldots, v_k$ be a path of length $k = \lfloor(e-1)/n\rfloor$ in $G$.

Now each neighbor of $v_0$ should be one of the $v_i$'s, for otherwise we can extend this path and get a path of length at least $\lfloor (e-1)/n\rfloor + 1 \geq \lfloor e/n\rfloor $. Let $G' = (V', E')$ be the graph obtained by deleting the vertex $v_0$. Then $e' := |E'| \geq e - k$. By induction we have that $G'$ has a path of length at least $\lfloor e'/(n-1)\rfloor$. A simple computation shows that this last quantity is at least $\lfloor e/n\rfloor$ and we are done.

Comment: You can do about twice as well, and not really any better (note that $\frac{2e}{n}$ is the average degree of the graph). See:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629299/g-simple-graph-show-that-it-has-a-path-of-length-at-least-dfrac2mn-wh
And
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4279526/longest-path-no-longer-than-average-degree-of-vertices

Comment: Thank you. Thank really helps.